# kubernetes-maven-plugin and google cloud platform

Tags: docker, maven, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am using the [jkube kubernetes-maven-plugin](https://eclipse.dev/jkube/docs/kubernetes-maven-plugin/) and I am trying to push stuff to the artifact registry on google cloud platform. I currently have issues with the authentication:

While `k8s:build` creates a perfectly fine image with the correct name that I can push using `docker push`, it fails when using `k8s:push`.
The error is either

```
Error getting the version of the configured credential helper: Failed to start 'docker-credential-gcloud version' : Cannot run program "docker-credential-gcloud": CreateProcess error=2
```

Or

```
denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" denied on resource "project
```

depending on how I configured my %USER%/.docker/config.json. (first is with credHelper gcloud, second is with credHelper removed and using plain docker login)

btw: I am running Windows

I tried `gcloud auth configure-docker europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev`
`gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr`
and `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` without success

Comment: I found a solution. I used the authConfig tags with username (_json_key), password (encrypted service-account.json) and mvn --encrypt-password